# ReadFile() returns a blank data

Tags: c++, file-io, serial-port

I'm testing serial port communication by connecting COM port RD and TD pins together.
The COM port has been initialized before the code below is executed.

```
CString cs_Send = "F: 5000000 Hz, SF: 1.0, Phase: 10, Position: 50, on sample 1";

BOOL bWriteRC = false;
BOOL bReadRC = false;
DWORD iBytesWritten = 0;
char readBuffer[256] = {"\0"};

DWORD read;

bWriteRC = WriteFile(hPort,cs_Send.GetBuffer(10),cs_Send.GetLength(),&iBytesWritten,NULL);
**Sleep(1000);// Thanks for the advice!!! this Sleep() will fix this error.**
bReadRC = ReadFile(hPort,readBuffer,sizeof(readBuffer),&read,NULL);

if(bWriteRC)
{
    if(bReadRC)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(readBuffer, MB_OK);
    }
}
```

The bWriteRC and bReadRC always return true. But the first message is completely blank. And if I run this more than twice, every message after the 1st is exactly same as what I sent. I wonder why the first one is always blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically the `WriteFile` and `WriteFileEx` functions write data to an internal buffer that the operating system writes to a disk or communication pipe on a regular basis. The `FlushFileBuffers` function writes all the buffered information for a specified file to the device or pipe.

call `FlushFileBuffers` after calling `WriteFile`.

See [FlushFileBuffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364439%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: It doesn't work with FlushFileBuffers(hPort) after WriteFile(). **The first message is still blank.**

Comment: what is the value of `read` variable after calling `ReadFile` ? And How did you call `CreateFile`?

Comment: I added `char csize[256] = {"\0"};` then add `itoa(read, csize, 10);` after ReadFile(). The first value always 0 and every next one is 61. CreateFile() is called well and it has been always initialized before the testing. 1 Byte-wise transmission was successful and I wanted to complete CString-wise test.

Comment: What if you add a delay between write and read? I think it is a matter of latency over serial port. add 1 second delay just for test.

Comment: Holly-shit!!! You are great. There was a delay!!! Now it works with Sleep(1000); after WriteFile()!!!!